# Can I pass the output of my network through a function and then calculate the gradient?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient

I want to pass the output of my DNN through an optimization function, and by having the the output of that function and the desired value, calculate the loss value and the gradient afterwards.

Here is an example of my code:

```
def train_step(x, y):
    # Use tf.GradientTape to record the gradients
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        # Compute the logits (predictions) of the model
        Gamma= model(x, training=True)
        # Pass through my function
        SNR = my_function(some_arameters, Gamma) 
        loss_value = loss_fn(y, SNR)
    # Get the gradients of the trainable weights with respect to the loss
    grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)
    # Update the weights using the optimizer
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
    # Update the accuracy metric
    train_acc_metric.update_state(y, logits)
    # Return the loss value
    return loss_value
```

Comment: Have you tried it at all? Do you understand that the loss function is also just a function that you pass the network outputs through?

Comment: @xdurch0 Ye. I tried both outside of loss function and inside of loss function definition and it gives me the error that it cannot find the gradient.